Three 7-letter words, 21 unique letters, excludes either HM or QS
I'm looking for three seven letter words consisting of 21 unique letters, and the final result must exclude either the letters HM or QS (Excluding S may be impossible based off of my own attempts). One word MUST include V. The closest I was able to get by hand (admittedly without the excluded letters) is:

Swarthy Flocked Bumping (or Jumping)
Mitzvah Cyborgs Flunked (or Plunked)

Please use the YAWL wordlist.

Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Is this a puzzle of your own creation, or is it one you've found elsewhere and are trying to solve?

@F1Krazy, it doesn't look like a puzzle. I looks like a step in the preparation of a puzzle. (Or a programming exercise.) I guess OP is looking for ways how to go about such constraints. The [tag:puzzle-creation] tag might be useful.

I dabble in agrammatical pangrams, like Pa Xi Jo Qs Brazing Kvetchy Mudflow.

@MOehm from my understanding, that tag is for when the question is about how to create a puzzle, not when the result will be incidentally used for a puzzle. This puzzle could just be a little brainteaser, as-written.

@bobble: Touché. This was the first of OP's questions and the requirements looked as if they might be needed to create a specific puzzle, but the current puzzle is just more of the same with changed requirements. It's not a classical brainteaser imo, because most people here will just see it as a nice programming exercise. So, yeah, I proposed that tag, but it's probably not appropriate, since OP claims just to "dabble in pangrams".

Here are some found solutions, there should be all of them in the given word list.
#     WORD1     WORD2     WORD3    UNUSED
-----------------------------------------
1    BRAZING + KVETCHY + MUDFLOW    JPQSX
2    FLIGHTY + PROVEND + ZAMBUCK    JQSWX
3    PERVING + TWYFOLD + ZAMBUCK    HJQSX
4    PREVING + TWYFOLD + ZAMBUCK    HJQSX
5    PROVEND + WIGHTLY + ZAMBUCK    FJQSX

Five solutions only...
@Lukas Rotter Many thanks for pointing out the error in the previous version!

Used newly UPDATED py code:
ALL_LETTERS = set('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')

words = []
with open('word.list') as stream:
    for line in stream.readlines():
        word = line.strip()
        if len(word) == 7 and len(set(word)) == 7:
            words.append(word.upper())

print(len(words))

vowels = set('AEIOUY')
dic = {}    # vowels --> list of words involving these vowels

for word in words:
    used_vowels = list(vowels.intersection(word.upper()))
    used_vowels.sort()
    used_vowels = ''.join(used_vowels)

    if used_vowels not in dic:
        dic[used_vowels] = []
        
    dic[used_vowels].append(word)
    
keys = list(dic)
keys.sort()

solutions = []
for ae in keys:
    for io in keys:
        if io <= ae:    continue 
        if set(ae).intersection(io):    continue
        for uy in keys:
            if uy <= io:    continue
            if set(uy).intersection(ae + io):    continue

            # print(f"TRYING {ae} {io} {uy}")
            for ae_word in dic[ae]:
                for io_word in dic[io]:
                    if len(set(ae_word + io_word)) < 14:    continue
                    for uy_word in dic[uy]:
                        letters = ae_word + io_word + uy_word
                        if len(set(letters)) < 21:    continue

                        unused = list(ALL_LETTERS.difference(letters))
                        unused . sort()
                        if ( 'V' in letters
                             and ( set('HM').issubset(unused) or 
                                   set('QS').issubset(unused) ) ):

                            sol = [ae_word, io_word, uy_word]
                            sol.sort()

                            solutions.append((sol, ''.join(unused)))

solutions.sort()
for counter, (sol, unused) in enumerate(solutions):
    ae_word, io_word, uy_word = sol
    print(f'    {counter + 1}    {ae_word} + {io_word} + {uy_word}    {unused}')
                  

(The code was rearranged in the final check condition to be simpler to digest also for readers that have no or limited python experience.)

Most if these do not have the required exclusions.

@DanielMathias Oh, there was too much copy+paste... i have 'HM' twice in the code... ok, i will edit, thanks for directing my attention...

I have no idea about python, but it looks like intersection() searches for the string "HM" rather than the chars ['h', 'm'], which is why there are so many invalid solutions here.

Let us take an example. ALL_LETTERS is a set in python. Then something like ALL_LETTERS.intersection('HM') takes the method intersection of the set instance, and applies it as "intersection with all letters" with the given argument. When this argument is a set, then it is ok. When not, it's converted to a set. In our case, set('HM') is {'H', 'M'}. So we intersect all letters with the set of individual letters in the string 'HM'. You can try the code on each computer, install python, if not already there, the OP file should be in ., then start pyhton and copy+paste the code.

The code produces solutions, if this issue with H and M would really be an issue, then BOSTRYX + FLUMPED + VACKING would show up on position $31$, with missing letters  HJQWZ. @LukasRotter

One of us misunderstands the question. How is ABVOLTS + GRUMPHY + ZINCKED valid? It is neither missing H&M nor Q&S.

@LukasRotter Yes, thanks for the comment insisting on the point, it was me who completely misunderstood. The previous condition was INcluding V, and either both HM, or both QS...

The MVP here is the St John Ambulance attendant

 brazing, kvetchy, mudflowflighty, provend, zambuckperving, twyfold, zambuckpreving, twyfold, zambuckprovend, wightly, zambuck


Out of interest, how did you derive this list? Particular software? Code?

@Stiv I wrote code for it which uses precomputed Set<char>s for each word for faster filtering.
